# How should we keep visual styles and templates up to date across microservices

Tags: css, styles, microservices

We're developing several microservices in parallel. I'm aware that best practice in microservice architecture doesn't necessarily require code sharing and reuse between services, but in the case of maintaining consistent styling between services with Web UIs it seems like it would be advantageous.

What are efficient ways of managing replicating the styles, avoiding manual edits of each service every time there is a layout or style update?

Comment: Can you explain the -1?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you mean a way how to reuse styles in multiple micro-frontend applications.
I would suggest to import your css styles from a shared library and reuse it in your micro-frontend apps. 
You can do for example:

- create a npm package for your common css/sass/scss styles
- create a npm package for your common or shared ui components

If you do an update some style in one of your libraries you just need to publish a new package and update to the new package in your micro-frontend apps.

> I'm aware that best practice in microservice architecture doesn't
>   necessarily require code sharing and reuse between services, but in
>   the case of maintaining consistent styling between services with Web
>   UIs it seems like it would be advantageous.

Yes that is true and doing something like this is in most cases is recommended. In micro-services and/or micro-frontend it is a good Idea to separate common business logic agnostic things to libraries. In case of micro-frontend that would be common styles, ui components, common utilities, test infrastructure and similar. In case of backend micro-services that would be data-access Repository base classes, cache handling, test infrastructure and similar. Otherwise you would duplicate these things in every micro-frontend/micro-service and applying fixes and changes to those components would be very hard to maintain. Still if you need some specific ui-component, style specific to your case you can still create a dedicated one in your micro-frontend, but keep the common ones in a library.

Additionally what you could do is include that style in some top Index.html or base Component of your UI and you would have it available in all sub html and/or Component files. Obviously this depends on how you structure your html/css and which FE framework 
you use.